# How does the override for the default.props occur

Tags: reactjs

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it!!

How does this message param:

```
return <Spinner message="Please accept location request" />;
```

overrides defaultProps `message` in Spinner.js

```
Spinner.defaultProps = { message: 'Loading...' } in spinner.js?
```

spinner.js:

```
                import React from 'react';

            const Spinner = (props) => {
                return (
                <div className="ui active dimmer">
                    <div className="ui big text loader">
                    {props.message}
                    </div>
                </div>
                );
            };


            Spinner.defaultProps = {
                message: 'Loading...'

            }

            console.log(Spinner);
            export default Spinner;
```

Comment: index.js is really hard to read

Comment: @jadeite1000 fwiw i removed your index.js image. it's not readable and it doesn't have relevance for this question. avoid pasting code image :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Spinner.defaultProps = { message: 'Loading...' }
```

it is equivalent to:

```
const Spinner = ({ message = 'Loading...' }) => { }
```

both situations you have a default value to message param for cases when you don't pass any message value. if you call `Spinner` without message param like `<Spinner />`, the default message `Loading...` will be displayed. if you pass a message value to spinner than that message will be used at your component.

Comment: When you passed a message: return <Spinner message="Please accept location request" />;  how did it over-ride the default message Spinner.defaultProps = {message: 'Loading...'}

Comment: I was expecting that even if you pass a message, the Spinner.defaultProps = {message: 'LOading..'} would take precedence?

Comment: that wouldn't make much sense in my view. if defaultProps would take precedence than it wouldn't have a point to have a `message` prop since would be static. you would only need to declare a constant variable inside the function not some prop.

Comment: defaultProps  means "if I don't receive a value, please use this value instead. Otherwise I would be undefined"

Comment: In the spinner.js, if I have the following:                                                                   
   <div className="ui big text loader">
            {props.message || 'Loading..'}
            </div>

Comment: I would not need Spinner.defaultProps = {
    message: 'Loading...'

}

Comment: so this code: const Spinner = ({ message = 'Loading...' }) => { } if we have return <Spinner message="Please accept location request" />; we basically overwrite the value for the variable message?

Comment: yes you are correct, you wouldn't need indeed. people, though, likes to use destructuring params. when you do `({ message = 'Loading..' }) => {}` you are extracting message from and defining a default value. you would only need to do `<div className="ui big text loader"> { message } </div>`

Comment: Hi Buzatto, I already change to "1". How do you change it to "accept as the accepted answer?"